# I don't understand why my form at my website ( https://www.ictcircle.tech/contact.html ) is not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, forms, freeze

I am using Bootstrap 4 and i have included all the scripts (Jquery, popper, and even tether.js) yet the form is just frozen and i really don't understand why.

I have tried using different browsers and yet the form fields appear disabled or something, Nothing seems to work, not even the submit button

I am using pug as the and i am sure i writing the proper syntax

```
form
    .form-group

        label(for="exampleInputEmail1") Email address

        input(type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" 
        aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email")

        small(id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted") We'll never 
        share your email with anyone else.

    .form-group

        label(for="exampleInputPassword1") Password

        input(type="password" class="form-control" 
        id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password")

    .form-check

        input(type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" 
        id="exampleCheck1")
        label(class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1") Check me out

    button(type="submit" class="btn btn-primary") Submit
```

I think am doing something wrong but i can seem to find it.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by *form is just frozen*?

converted HTML code looks fine.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form>
  <div class="form-group"><label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label><input class="form-control" type="email" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email" /><small class="form-text text-muted" id="emailHelp">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small></div>
  <div class="form-group"><label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label><input class="form-control" type="password" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password" /></div>
  <div class="form-check"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="exampleCheck1" /><label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label></div><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Please see the live form at my website ictcircle.tech/contact.html I dont understand why it does not work

Comment: I found the bug, I had the container z-index set to 10, while the alert-box containing my form had a lower z-index of 1. This was blocking all clicks. Thanks for you help though